# Union Two files by column using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to Union/Merge two files using pig. But, this is a different union than a usual union. Following are my files (h* are header of files) :

```
F1 : 
h1,h2,h3,h4
a01,a02,a03,a04
a11,a12,a13,a14

F2 : 
h3,h4,h5,h6
a23,a24,b01,b02
a33,a34,b11,b12
```

The resulting output must be a Union of these files like this :

```
FR :
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 
a01,a02,a03,a04,,
a11,a12,a13,a14,,
,,a23,a24,b01,b02
,,a33,a34,b11,b12
```

One more difficulty is I want to make it generic so that it works for dynamic number of common columns. Currently there are two common columns, it could have 3 or 1 common column or even no common column at all. For example :

```
F1 :
h1,h2,h3,h4
a1,a2,a3,a4

F2
h5,h6,h7,h8
b1,b2,b3,b4

FR
a1,a2,a3,a4
,,,,b1,b2,b3,b4
```

Any hint/help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it statically:

```
F1full = FOREACH F1 GENERATE h1,h2,h3,h4, NULL as h5, NULL as h6;
F2full = FOREACH F2 GENERATE NULL as h1,NULL as h2,h3,h4, h5, h6;

FR = F1full UNION F2full;
```

Pig is not very flexible, so I don't think it is possible to generate this dynamically/for the generic case.

If you would want a solution for the generic case, you could use a language like python to build the required command based on metadata of stored tables/files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the problem using following approach :

```
1) Load both of the files. 
2) Add counter to generate a unique field (ID).
3) Start the counter for file B where counter for A ended.
4) Cogroup both files with common columns, including counteer.
5) Take all group columns in a different schema.
6) Generate uncommon columns from both files, along with the counter.
7) First join uncommon columns from file A with group columns on counter.
8) Join the result of step 7 with uncommon columns from file B on counter.
```

Following is the pig script to do the same. As this script is generic, I have mentioned what all parameters will be required before running the script.

```
-- Parameters required : $file1_path, $file2_path, $file1_schema, $file2_schema, $COUNT_A (number of rows in file A), $CMN_COLUMN_A (common columns in A), $CMN_COLUMN_B, $UNCMN_COLUMN_A(Unique columns in file A), $UNCMN_COLUMN_B.
A = LOAD '$file1_path' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('~',  'NO_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') as ($file1_schema);
B = LOAD '$file2_path' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('~',  'NO_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') as ($file2_schema);

RANK_A = RANK A;
RANK_B = RANK B;
COUNT_RANK_B = FOREACH RANK_B GENERATE ($0+(long)'$COUNT_A') as rank_B, $1 ..;

COGRP_RANK_AB = COGROUP RANK_A BY($CMN_COLUMN_A), COUNT_RANK_B BY ($CMN_COLUMN_B);

CMN_COGRP_RANK_AB = FOREACH COGRP_RANK_AB GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS ($CMN_COLUMN_A);
UNCMN_RB = FOREACH COUNT_RANK_B GENERATE $UNCMN_COLUMN_B;

JOIN_CMN_UNCMN_A = JOIN CMN_COGRP_RANK_AB BY(rank_A) LEFT OUTER, UNCMN_RA by rank_A;
JOIN_CMN_UNCMN_B = JOIN JOIN_CMN_UNCMN_A BY(CMN_COGRP_RANK_AB::rank_A) LEFT OUTER, UNCMN_RB by rank_B;

STORE FINAL_DATA INTO '$store_path' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('~', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'WRITE_OUTPUT_HEADER');
```

Comment: Would this require one to manually specify which columns are unique and common for each table? Or does it come with a programmatic way to provide the input variables.

Comment: I have a wrapper to this script which finds out programmatically all the variables. I am using the same script to union n number of files, so I can not provide manually for all files.